# how to know size of data before calling SQLGetData

Tags: c++, odbc

I want to know the exact size of the data available in a table before I call the `SQLGetData` function. Currently I am following the code listed below, which works for me, but I am not sure whether it is safe.

Can anyone help me?

```
char*ptr = new char[0];


        if (retcode = SQLGetData(hstmt, 31, SQL_C_BINARY, ptr,0,&cbfdata) != SQL_NO_DATA)
        {
            delete[] ptr;
            vector<char> vec(cbfdata);

            SQLGetData(hstmt, 31, SQL_C_BINARY, &vec[0],cbfdata,&cbfdata);

            ofstream fout;
            fout.open(file,ios::binary);
            fout.write(&vec[0],cbfdata);
            fout.close();
            vec.clear();
        }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

calling SQLGetData without pointer (NULL) returns 7 in cbfdata ,which is not actual size.

i have tried creating 0 size pointer and deleting it in other small project. it do not fails.

however not taking risk, i improve code little bit by placing delete at end and increasing size

to 1 byte.

```
        char*ptr = new char[1];

        if (retcode = SQLGetData(hstmt, 31, SQL_C_BINARY, ptr,0,&cbfdata) != SQL_NO_DATA)
        {
            vector<char> vec(cbfdata);
            SQLGetData(hstmt, 31, SQL_C_BINARY, &vec[0],cbfdata,&cbfdata);

            ofstream fout;
            fout.open(file,ios::binary);
            fout.write(&vec[0],cbfdata);
            fout.close();
            vec.clear();
        }
        delete[] ptr;
```

Comment: Instead of allocating an array of length 1, you can just use the stack, like: `char c; if (retcode = SQLGetData(hstmt, 31, SQL_C_BINARY, &c,0,&cbfdata) != SQN_NO_DATA) ...`

Comment: Please, note also that this is only valid for SQL_C_BINARY data or when there isn't any character set conversion implied, otherwise cbfdata may receive SQL_NO_TOTAL (see [this SQLGetData page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-api/sqlgetdata)). In this case, you are stuck with a loop retrieving chunks of data without knowing the total length.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson actually it would throw and leak `ptr`. `SQL_NO_TOTAL` defined as `-4` and overflows in `vector` constructor accepting `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call SQLGetData without a data ptr first and the StrLen_or_IndPtr set and the driver will write the size into StrLen_or_IndPtr.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

At least not in a safe, generic way. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/getting-long-data?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> The value returned in the length/indicator buffer decreases in each
>   call by the number of bytes returned in the previous call, **although it
>   is common for the driver to be unable to discover the amount of
>   available data and return a byte length of SQL_NO_TOTAL**.

(emphasis mine)

---

Let me give you an example:

1. Let us assume that your field is of type  `NVARCHAR` in the result set.
2. Your target buffer is a C-string.
3. Therefore, the ODBC driver will have to convert from wide character to narrow character.
4. The driver may choose to do the conversion in `SQLGetData` "on the fly", while copying data from its fetch buffer to your target buffer.
5. One wide character (in the driver's fetch buffer) can take 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes in your target buffer. It is impossible to tell unless the data has actually been converted. If conversion and copying is done in one step, well ...